# Same property under different classes or one class with one property

Tags: css

I have a css file with around 1800 lines. 11 classes, among other properties, contain `margin-bottom: 0;`.

I was wondering if it would be better to make a separate class, for example `.mar-bott {margin-bottom: 0;}` and add it to HTML or should I leave it like this? Would it affect the loading time?

Comment: CSS doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should leave it like it is, otherwhise you could create classes for every css property, and I do not think that is the point of css. The point of CSS is to shorten the HTML code, and to make it understandable.

As long as you know what each of your class does I would not create extra classes.

That is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually what Bootstrap 4 is doing with the mt, mb, my, mx (margin-top, bottom, y, x).

As Serge said, you shouldn't abuse that with every CSS property but in my case, I often do that with margin and padding so if your margin/padding are wrong, you just have to change the value in the class.

Just a short example of the classes I create when i start a new project (i'm actually doing the same as bootstrap):

```
mt-5{
     margin-top: 30px;
}
mt-4{
     margin-top: 25px;
}
mt-3{
     margin-top: 20px;
}
mt-2{
     margin-top: 15px;
}
mt-1{
     margin-top: 10px;
}
```

And so on ... :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make it a separate class. Less css means less data needs to be fetched from the server

Comment: Is it ok for HTML to have many (like 4-5) classes? I'm just wondering what the convention is.

Comment: @Al-josh there is no convention, all depends on your situation, project, works, etc .... we can tell you that the use of `!important` is bad but check the bootstrap CSS and you will find a ton of `!important`